# Ubuntu 18.04 gnuplot has random segmentation faults

Tags: 18.04, segmentation-fault, gnuplot

I am trying to draw the most basic plot using gnuplot in the terminal and simply entering :

```
gnuplot> plot 'histogramme.dat' u 1:3
```

leads to :

```
gnuplot> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I can produce image files, but not display on screen, which is highly inconvenient... Would anyone have met the same problem and have a solution, by any chance ?

Have a good day !

Marc

Add.

ldd seems to see no missing library

the default terminal is wxt 0 enhanced

I installed gnuplot using apt

I'll have a try with memtest/strace asap ! The only problem being that this error is quite random (currently, I am using gnuplot without any problem... I am also going to make tests on my data files, but they're quite large, so I am not entirely confident in conclusive examination at this point).

Comment: That error usually deals with a memory problem. quoting In computing, a segmentation fault or access violation is a fault, or failure condition, raised by hardware with memory protection, notifying an operating system the software has attempted to access a restricted area of memory. On standard x86 computers, this is a form of general protection fault

Comment: Suggest you run the memtest program.

Comment: Try double-quotes for the filename, and also check that the file is accessible, and in the correct format. Perhaps pastebin and example of the file. Else gnuplot will potentially read bad data, which I suspect leads to the memory error once it overflows.

Comment: maybe start the program with a debugger or `strace`to find out which lib causes the crash#! Which gnuplot version are you using, apt , .... ?

Comment: `ldd $(which gnuplot)` run this in a terminal and search for missing libaries !

Comment: Useful information to add to your question would be how you installed gnuplot (from the repository? if so, which package - `gnuplot-x11` or `gnuplot-qt` or `gnuplot-nox`? or from a snap or flatpak? or from source?). What is the default reminal type (ex. `gnuplot -e 'show term'`)?

Comment: Thanks a lot to you all for your suggestions ! I have edited my post to answer all the ones I could deal with rapidly... and will keep investigating asap...